# Change default recipient bank in Customer invoice

Tags: odoo, odoo-15, odoo-accounting

In customer invoices (v15) how to change default Recipient Bank - as shown on screenshot

[image]

Thank you!

Comment: How is this programming related?

Comment: As everything in Odoo I believe this could be solved using code. I haven't been able to find where in configuration this can be changed and that's why I'm asking for help. Do you think this is against community guidelines?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change it from Partner form, Open **your company partner** and then from **Accounting tab**, you can add and remove bank accounts under bank accounts group as you can see in the below image.

**Note**: If you have multiple bank accounts, you can drag and drop the bank account (you want to use as default in invoices) to the beginning of the list so Odoo will use it as default bank account in invoices.

[image: Company Partner Form]

Comment: Yes, this could work but I was asking for default account when creating new invoice (not default for customer but general default) and the answer is ordering in Bank Accounts (thank you - this is first meaningfull answer)

Comment: This is not default for customer, You will add bank accounts to your company partner only.

Comment: True, set your answer as correct one. Thank you Waleed!

Answer (score 0):

The key is in the ordering of Bank Accounts

Go to Contacts > Configuration > Bank Accounts and for your company drag the bank account that needs to be default in the first place (screenshot only for reference)

[image]